# Limit calculation with Taylor series

Tags: taylor-expansion, limits-without-lhopital

1. By finding the limit as $x\to0$ (using Taylor series)  $\dfrac{e^x -1}{x}$, I got $e^x = 1 + x + \dfrac{x^2}{2} + ... $ so $e^x -1 = x +
       \dfrac{x^2}{2} + O(x^2)$. But the derivative of $\dfrac{1}{x}$ gives
   $-\dfrac{1}{x^2}$ by inserting(while calculating taylor series) $0$
   when I try to compute Taylor series of $\dfrac{1}{x}$ it gives me
   $\dfrac{1}{0}$. can someone check where I made a mistake?

Comment: What limit? $x\to 0$?

Comment: @ZacharySelk yes x --> 0.

Comment: That is relevant information. :)

Comment: sorry i will edit it again :-)

Comment: $\frac{e^x-1}{x} = 1 + x/2 + O(x^2)$ so the limit as $x$ goes to $0$ is $1$

Comment: Do we always need taylor series for both(numerator and denominator) or we can compute taylor series only for $e^x -1$ and then divide both side both(numerator and denominator) by x?

Comment: As you did by subtracting $1$ on the Taylor expansion of $e^x$ you can also divide the expansion by $x$ !

Comment: They Taylor series for $x$ is just $x$

Answer (score 1):

If you want to evaluate $\lim_\limits{x\to 0}\dfrac{e^x -1}{x}$ using Taylor series, you just need to know $e^x -1 = x + O(x)$.
Then you have $\lim_\limits{x\to 0}\dfrac{x}{x}$ which is $1$.